# How to read mouse delta in Quartz events?

Tags: macos, core-graphics, quartz

In a Quartz application, I am trying to freeze the mouse *pointer* on the screen but continue to register mouse *mouvements* from the user. I have found how to freeze the pointer:

```
CGAssociateMouseAndMouseCursorPosition(false);
```

I am following the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1454486-cgassociatemouseandmousecursorpo) but don't know how to get and read *events that contain mouse delta (change in X and Y) data*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I am now getting the mouse movements like this:

```
CGEventMask eventMask = CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventMouseMoved);
CFMachPortRef tap = CGEventTapCreate(   kCGAnnotatedSessionEventTap, 
                                        kCGHeadInsertEventTap, 
                                        kCGEventTapOptionListenOnly, 
                                        eventMask, 
                                        eventOccurred, 
                                        NULL);
CFRunLoopSourceRef rl = CFMachPortCreateRunLoopSource(kCFAllocatorDefault, tap, 0);
CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetMain(), rl, kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
CGEventTapEnable(tap, true);
```

where the callback is:

```
CGEventRef eventOccurred(CGEventTapProxy proxy, CGEventType type, CGEventRef event, void* refcon) {
    if (type == kCGEventMouseMoved) {
        d_x =  CGEventGetIntegerValueField(event, kCGMouseEventDeltaX);
        d_y =  CGEventGetIntegerValueField(event, kCGMouseEventDeltaY);
    }
    return event;
}
```

Note: `d_x`and `d_y` are globally defined `int` that store the mouse movement between each event.